# Is there a way to permanently remove a tile "programmatically" (Java) from caching in GeoServer?

Tags: java, geoserver

I'm working with GeoServer and a Java backend. I am able to reset a tile's cache using the Rest API and to prevent any further cahing by removing the tile permanently from GeoServer's GUI (Tile Caching -> Tile Layers -> Check the tile -> Click on "Remove selected cached layers").

I would like to automatize the process and do it from back-end side. I tried truncate operations, dug in the rest api as well as Java objects but haven't been able to figure how.

Is is possible to permanently remove a tile from caching using Java? If yes, how?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to remove just one tile, or a whole layer. Either way rest is probably the best option

Comment: @IanTurton If I refer to the GeoServer's semantic, you are right, this is indeed a whole layer (the column is called "Layer Name"). I tried to find the information using the rest API but I was only able to find a way to clear the cache, not to prevent the layer to be in cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid caching a layer at all (rather than truncating a layer's cache) then you need to visit its  GWC REST endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/zoomstack:airports.xml
```

which will give you a file like:

```
<GeoServerLayer>
  <id>LayerInfoImpl-36bac688:1666e6c28d4:-7ffd</id>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <inMemoryCached>true</inMemoryCached>
  <name>zoomstack:airports</name>
  <mimeFormats>
    <string>image/png</string>
    <string>image/jpeg</string>
  </mimeFormats>
  <gridSubsets>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>osgb</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:900913</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:4326</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
  </gridSubsets>
  <metaWidthHeight>
    <int>4</int>
    <int>4</int>
  </metaWidthHeight>
  <expireCache>0</expireCache>
  <expireClients>0</expireClients>
  <parameterFilters>
    <styleParameterFilter>
      <key>STYLES</key>
      <defaultValue/>
    </styleParameterFilter>
  </parameterFilters>
  <gutter>0</gutter>
</GeoServerLayer>
```

You can then change `<enabled>true</enabled>` to `<enabled>false</enabled>` and PUT it back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Ian's answer (works like a charm, thank you Ian), here is a Java snippet (that needs some love, constants, etc.):

```
private void removeLayerGroupFromCache() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/layer group name.xml");
    String rawLayer = getXMLContent(url);
    String updatedLayer = formatXMLContent(rawLayer);
    updateLayerInGIS(url, updatedLayer);
}

private String getXMLContent(URL url) throws IOException {
    URLConnection urlConnection = setUsernamePassword(url);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    bufferedReader.close();
    inputStreamReader.close();

    return result.toString();
}

// TODO: This feels akward and should be improved. (Why extra spaces are being added with the urlConnection.getInputStream() call?)
private String formatXMLContent(String originalContent) {
    originalContent = originalContent.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Removes undesired spaces.
    originalContent = originalContent.replaceAll("layergroupname".replaceAll("\\s+", ""), "layer group name"); // Makes sure the name is matching if it contains white spaces.
    originalContent = originalContent.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>".replaceAll("\\s+", ""), "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"); // Re-append required spaces to XML declaration.
    originalContent = originalContent.replace("<enabled>true</enabled>", "<enabled>false</enabled>"); // Finally, disable the caching for the group.

    return originalContent;
}

private URLConnection setUsernamePassword(URL url) throws IOException {
    String authStringEncoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64("username:userpassword".getBytes()));
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEncoded);

    return urlConnection;
}

private void updateLayerInGIS(URL url, String updatedLayer) throws IOException {
    Authentication auth = authenticationResolver.retrieve();
    String encodedCredentials = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:userpassword".getBytes());
    URL directUrl = new URL("http", url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getFile());

    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) directUrl.openConnection();
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
    out.write(updatedLayer);
    out.close();

    int statusCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();

    if(statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 400) {
        httpCon.getInputStream();
    } else {
        // Gets a more verbose message on why a non valid code has been returned.
        String errorMessage = readStream(httpCon.getErrorStream());

        throw new IOException(errorMessage);
    }
}

private String readStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```